# Is there a convenient way to lower the resolution of pictures without additional software?

Tags: graphics, external-files

Background is that in my lab it is common and convenient to document stuff by simply making a picture of it. Once a project is finished, I will merge these pictures into one file which I will give to other group members so they can work with it. Since these files often contain 20+ images where each image is a few Mb the PDF-File gets quite large (>100Mb).

That is why I am wondering: Is there any convenient way in LaTex to lower the resolution of pictures without having to run them through another software beforehand ?

Comment: I would not consider this a duplicate since both answers suggest using additional software beforehand/afterwards.

Comment: Changind image resolution is a task for an image editor. I doubt Tex or pdflatex can do it properly,

Comment: @Christian you are right that the answers in the other question use additional software, however it can be fully automated from within your LaTeX file, so it might be a suitable approach for your issue.

Comment: For PDFTeX there are settings like `\pdfpxdimen` which is a TeX length. You can set the DPI with it, but it might just scale the image instead of reducing its file size.